# How to define date range and assign it to a variable in python

Tags: python, scripting

I need to amend an existing python sript which extracts data from previous day to extract data for last two weeks like biweekly data. Please advise how I can twik to get the date range in the variable

```
def parse_gov():
    reject_patterns = generate_reject_patterns()

    today_str = date.today().strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
    yesterday =
    yesterday_str = yesterday.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
    query_date = date.today()
```

So need to get the date range in yesterday variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use `timedelta` to do so. for example,

```py
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Many thanks. Will this fetch each date through the dat range say I mention days =14 as I want to get data for last two weeks ?

Comment: Of course, you can use `days` to specify the range and `-` or `+` between any date object and `timedelta` specifies *past* or *feature*. you can also use `weeks` if you need!

Comment: Got the below error when I ran the script.AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'